# How to decode a JSON array into Elm list of custom types

Tags: json, elm, decoder, custom-type

I want to decode a JSON array of payload objects into `List Payload` where each `Payload` is a custom type:

```
type Payload
     = PayloadP1 P1
     | PayloadP2 P2
```

After decoding `PayloadP1` and `PayloadP2` using decoders below how do I decode `Payload`?

```
type alias P1  = 
    { id : Int
    , st : String
    }

type alias P2  = 
    { id : Int
    , s1 : String
    , s2 : String
    }

type Payload
     = PayloadP1 P1
     | PayloadP2 P2

type alias PayloadQueue = List Payload

decodeP1 : Jd.Decoder P1
decodeP1 =
    Jd.map2 P1
        (Jd.field "id" Jd.int)
        (Jd.field "st" Jd.string)

decodeP2 : Jd.Decoder P2
decodeP2 =
    Jd.map3 P2
        (Jd.field "id" Jd.int)
        (Jd.field "p1" Jd.string)
        (Jd.field "p2" Jd.string)

decodePayload =
    Jd.field ".type" Jd.string
    |> Jd.andThen decodePayload_

{-
decodePayload_ : String -> Jd.Decoder Payload
decodePayload_ ptype =
    case ptype of
        "P1" -> decodeP1
        "P2" -> decodeP2
-}

json_str = """[
   {".type" : "P1", "id" : 1, "st" : "st"},
   {".type" : "P2", "id" : 2, "p1" : "p1", "p2" : "p2"},
]"""
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap `P1` and `P2` in `PayloadP1` and `PayloadP2` respectively in order to return a common type from each branch, which you can do using [`map`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/json/latest/Json-Decode#map). Then you also need to account for the possibility that the `type` field is neither `P1` or `P2`. In that case you can either provide a default or return an error using [`fail`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/json/latest/Json-Decode#fail). I've done the latter below.

```
decodePayload_ : String -> Jd.Decoder Payload
decodePayload_ ptype =
    case ptype of
        "P1" -> decodeP1 |> Jd.map PayloadP1
        "P2" -> decodeP2 |> Jd.map PayloadP2
        _ -> Jd.fail "invalid type"
```

Comment: It became clear after I realised that the signature for `PayloadP1` is `P1 -> Payload`. So in the definition of `map` from the `JSON` module map : `(a -> value) -> Decoder a -> Decoder value` variable `a` stands for `P1` and `value` stands for `Payload`.